# Fancy Dialog in Polymer For Videos, webpages.

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I was just started with `Polymer` by `Google` and writing `polymer webcomponents` . Actually i wanted to show webpages inside the same page with fancy dialog or want to show youtube videos for the same like this framework does : [Fancy Box](http://tutvid.com/webdesign/dreamweaver/how-to-use-fancybox-jquery-tutorial/).I tried lot ways but polymer seems to be very different style of coding for me . Please help me with your ideas .

Answer (score -1):

Your question is awfully generic, but if you're making a material design application you can import `paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html` and next do something like

```
<paper-dialog heading="Dialog Title">
  <p>Some content</p>
</paper-dialog>
```

To create a basic dialog. More documentation can be found [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-dialog).